# Unable to insert the date in SQL Server database using date time datatype

Tags: sql-server, date

I am trying to save a date into a SQL Server database using asp.net Calender control.

The data type I am using in the database for the date column is `datetime` or `date` (had tried using both)

In the backend of my asp.net code I am inserting the data using the following code in my sql section:

```
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LeaveTillDate", Calendar_LtD.SelectedDate);
```

Here comm is my `SqlCommand` object, `@LeaveTillDate` is one which sends the data to the query, `Calendar_LtD.SelectedDate` is the one which access the calender control value.

Can anyone please do explain me whats the error and whats the solution for it ?

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess that "SelectedDate" is not the right format. Check what the exact value of "SelectedDate" is and try writing a simple SQL query to insert it into your database manually. If that works then its another issue, if not then you'll nee to write some conversion code.

Comment: the exact value of selectedDate is some what in this format "dd/mm/yyyy hh/mm/ss" .
can you suggest some simple query as a example and what type of code conversion because i have also tried "SelectedDate.ToString(yyyy/mm/dd) "

Comment: if you can capture the whole SQL query that it attempts to run there could be an error in there. Copy the SQL examples of both the things you've tried

Comment: Hey, if this has solved your problem can you mark it as the right answer? Cheers, Mal